# Perl Moose parent class cast with child

Tags: perl, oop, moose

```
package Point;
use Moose;

has 'x' => (isa => 'Int', is => 'rw');
has 'y' => (isa => 'Int', is => 'rw');

package Point3D;
use Moose;

extends 'Point';

has 'z' => (isa => 'Int', is => 'rw');

package main;

use Data::Dumper;

my $point1 = Point->new(x => 5, y => 7);
my $point3d = Point3D->new(z => -5);

$point3d = $point1;
print Dumper($point3d);
```

Is it possible to cast a parent to child class such as c++? In my examble is $point3d now a Point and not a Point3D include the Point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [Class::MOP documentation on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Class-MOP-1.11/lib/Class/MOP/Class.pm#Object_instance_construction_and_cloning), especially the `clone_object` and `rebless_instance` methods:

```
sub to_3d {
  my ($self, %args) = @_;
  return Point3D->meta->rebless_instance(
    $self->meta->clone_object($self),
    %args,
  );
}
```

And then use it like the following:

```
my $point_3d = $point->to_3d(z => 7);
```

This will also take care to treat the newly specified `%args` as if they've been passed in by the constructor. E.g. builders, defaults, and type constraints are all considered during this build.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to cast in Perl, since it is a dynamic language.  In your case though, the variable `$point3d` contains a reference to a `Point` object at the end of the script.  You cannot treat this as a `Point3D` *because it is not a `Point3D`.*  You could manually *convert* it, but you can't "remake" an existing object as a different class.  (Well, you theoretically can in Perl, but you shouldn't.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Dumper` should tell you that `$point3d` is now a `Point`, not a `Point3D`, because your assignment of `$point3d = $point1` makes `$point3d` a second reference to the same object as `$point1`.  The `Point3D` instance that was originally referenced by `$point3d` is now lost in space with a refcount of 0, making it eligible for garbage collection.

As cdhowie said, you don't really do typecasting in Perl the way you do in C/C++.  The closest I can think of is to fall back on the non-OO calling convention and use, e.g., `Point3D::z($point1, 4)` to give `$point1` a z-index of 4, but that's kind of clumsy and you'd have to use the same syntax for any future references to it's z-index.  Note also that, when using this calling convention, `Point3D` *must* actually define a `z` method[1] or you'll get a runtime error because inheritance doesn't work when you do it this way because you're referring to `Point3D` as a package, not to `$point1` as an object.

If you want to actually make your `Point` into a `Point3D`, you can easily change the actual type of an object using `bless` (the same command used to change a plain reference into an object in the first place, although that's hidden inside of Moose in your example code), but I suspect that manually reblessing a Moose object would anger the Moose.  (But, if that is the case, I'm sure Moose provides a safer way of changing an object's class.  I just don't use Moose enough to know what it would be.)

[1] ...or `AUTOLOAD`, but that's an entirely different can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I am seconding what cdhowie and Dave S. said, but one more thing to add.

If you DO want to make `$point3d` which holds an object of class `Point` into a real object of subclass `Point3D`, the correct OO way of doing it is by creating a constructor `new_from_Point()` in `Point3D` class, which takes an object of class `Point` as input and creates an `Point3D` object (it should probably take an extra "z" parameter). The C++ equivalent would be a constructor with a signature of `(const Point &, double &z=0.0)`